# Maven release plugin skipping tests on perform but not prepare

Tags: java, maven

When using the maven release plugin, both `mvn release:prepare` and `mvn release:perform` will run the tests.

Is there any way I can configure things so they only run during `mvn release:prepare`?

I know you can pass:

```
-Darguments="-DskipTests"
```

But this will skip the tests during both goals, which I don't want. And I also don't want them to run during just `mvn release:perform` and not prepare, as a failure during perform will have already tagged the repository.

Comment: This looks relevant http://maven.40175.n5.nabble.com/Skip-tests-on-release-td2456830.html

Answer (score 5):

You should be able to do that by adding the `<releaseProfiles>` element to the release-plugin configuration. This will only be used for release:perform Mojo.

Something like this should do the trick:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <releaseProfiles>skipTestsForReleasePerform</releaseProfiles>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
(...)
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>skipTestsForReleasePerform</id>
        <properties>
            <maven.test.skip>true</maven.test.skip>
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

Comment: I was experimenting with profiles. My problem is further complicated by Jenkins not allowing you to parameterize your release goals separately. There's only a single box for your goals and parameters for a release.I ended up solving this by having the job just run release:prepare as normal and then a post build action running the release:perform without tests only on a real release (which is known by Jenkins setting an environment variable). Hacky and not exactly the Maven way but it ended up doing the job well enough.

Comment: By using what I answered, you should not be forced to change anything in the Maven command, everything is specified in the POM, we just "force" the release plugin to add -Pxxx with the releaseProfile element.

Comment: Works like a charm!